# Can I run async code synchronously?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, synchronous

I wanted to try [pyppeteer](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer) package, but it feels like using `async` would be an overkill for my little script. Is there a way to run asynchronous code synchronously? Here's what I tried:

```
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  3 2017, 21:45:48) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
[15:42:45]>>> import pyppeteer
[15:42:47]>>> browser = pyppeteer.launch()
[15:42:49]>>> pg = browser.newPage()
[15:42:52]>>> pg.goto('about:blank')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'goto'
[15:42:55]>>> exit()
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Browser.newPage' was never awaited
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a package like [`aioconsole`](https://aioconsole.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the same

```
pip3 install aioconsole
```

After that instead of running `python` you run `apython` and then you can use `await` statements in Python REPL

```
>>> import pyppeteer
>>> browser = pyppeteer.launch()
>>> pg = await browser.newPage()
>>> await pg.goto('http://tarunlalwani.com')
<pyppeteer.network_manager.Response object at 0x10ee84860>
>>> resp = _
>>> vars(resp)
{'_client': <pyppeteer.connection.Session object at 0x10ee5f940>, '_request': <pyppeteer.network_manager.Request object at 0x10ee840f0>, 'status': 200, '_contentPromise': <Future pending>, 'ok': True, 'url': 'http://tarunlalwani.com/', '_headers': {'date': 'Sat, 10 Mar 2018 02:28:04 GMT', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'last-modified': 'Sun, 10 Sep 2017 22:04:41 GMT', 'server': 'GitHub.com', 'x-github-request-id': 'E7AC:5FCC:6030CBE:86341C1:5AA342B4', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'cache-control': 'max-age=600', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'expires': 'Sat, 10 Mar 2018 02:38:04 GMT'}}
```

Comment: The OP is using a script, and only used a console session to illustrate their issue.